# Python: filenames with german umlaut

Tags: python, file, copy, diacritics

I have the following problem with copying files:

I am getting a list of file names and some of them can contain an umlaut. Example: part1üpart2.txt. In my list this shows up as 'part1\xfcpart2.txt'. So I know that the character ü is represented as \xfc. How to I copy the file such that it has the name part1üpart2.txt and not part1\xfcpart2.txt?

My script has # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- and I tried to remove the escape \ with unicode and a lot of other stuff, but no success.

This is on WinXP and Python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: Post your code here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shutil.copy(u"part1üpart2.txt",dst)
```

is working for me. Just use unicode strings.

Comment: yes - it does work, it writes correctly, even when the string has the escape sequence. I did not realize that there was another problem unrelated to the umlaut.